# How to download other different deb files with apt-get in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, debian, raspberrypi

Is there any way how to download another version of deb files with apt-get in Ubuntu 12.04? In Ubuntu 12.04, the default version is precise, and when we use the sudo apt-get install ** command to install packages, the apt-get can find the suitable packages automatically. But is there any way to download the deb packages with specific version, such as Ubuntu 10.04(Lucid)? In my circumstance, I have an Raspberry Pi, its main version is Debian and its symbol version is wheezy. When I use the sudo apt-get install **, the network speed is very slow. So I want to add the apt source address of wheezy into my Ubuntu 12.04's apt source addresses. And use the Ubuntu 12.04 to download the wheezy's packages, then copy them into the Raspberry Pi and install.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than damage your main system with an incompatible archive, an appropriate tool such as **apt-offline** is available in the [Wheezy archive](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/apt-offline) as well as for [12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/apt-offline).  That package would allow you to set up your package download request on the Pi, copy it to removable media, download the packages on the 12.04 system, and then be able to safely take them back to the Pi for installation without damaging the 12.04 through introducing incompatibility issues.

Comment: Hi, sir, thank you for reply. I have tested some methods. First, I add the `wheezy` apt source addresses into the `/etc/apt/sources.list` in `Ubuntu 12.04`, and in `Ubuntu 12.04`, do `sudo apt-get update`, then some apt cache has been created, and I can search some packages of version `wheezy`. But  when I use `sudo apt-get download cmake`, it says there is no `amd64` version. This is because the `Raspberry Pi` is arm-architecture. So I think if I can give a specific architecture version of the apt, it may work. But I haven't done this successfully.

Comment: The main error is `W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)`. So I think if I can replace the `amd64` with `armhf`, it maybe could work.

Comment: @research2010 That is an extremely destructive approach that ignored binary compatibility.  A cross-architecture approach like you describe will damage your system.

Comment: Yes! What you said is very correct! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888551/how-to-download-other-different-deb-files-with-apt-get-in-ubuntu, they all advise against doing like that.